# want to add values not overwrite react.js and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

```
function getFilterQuery() {
   const completedWorkState = WorkflowStates.findOne({title: 'Completed'});
   const inProgressWorkState = WorkflowStates.findOne({title: 'In Progress'});
   const identifiedWorkState = WorkflowStates.findOne({title: 'Identified'});
 
   const completed = {workflowStateId: [completedWorkState._id]};
   const inProgress = {workflowStateId: [inProgressWorkState._id]};
   const identified = {workflowStateId: [identifiedWorkState._id]};
   let finalQuery = {
     archived: false,
     boardId: {$in: boardIds},
     listId: {$nin: [...managerListIds, ...unreportedListIds]},
     createdAt: dateFilterQuery(),
   };
 
   if (params.completed) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...completed};
   if (params.inProgress) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...inProgress};
   if (params.identified) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...identified};
 
   console.log(`finalQuery:`, finalQuery);
   return finalQuery;
 }
```

Hi, I have a question about react.js and mongoDB.
If you click the completed option on the client side, finalQuery’s console log looks like below.

```
finalQuery:{ 
archived: false 
boardId: {$in: Array(0)} 
createdAt: undefined listId: {$nin: Array(0)} 
workflowStateId: ['ERTYUIIIIOPPCGVH']
 }
```

Ideally, if a user clicks multiple options like in progress or identified, finalQuery’ workflowStaeId should look like below when console logged.

```
workflowStateId: ['ERTYUIIIIOPPCGVH','asdasdasdasda','1231231dsxa']
```

But right now it’s just overwritten. Does anybody know how to solve this?

I tried to change codes

```
       if (params.completed) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...completed};
       if (params.inProgress) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...inProgress};
       if (params.identified) finalQuery = {...finalQuery, ...identified};
```

to

```
    if (params.completed) finalQuery.push(completed);
    if (params.inProgress) finalQuery.push(inProgress);
    if (params.identified) finalQuery.push(identified);
```

But got an error saying
finalQuery.push is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concat array in `finalQuery.workflowStateId`, but you only use object spread syntax to merge objects. You also have to use array spread syntax for `.workflowStateId` array which is nested in deeper level.

```
if (params.completed) finalQuery = {
  ...finalQuery,
  ...{
    workflowStateId:
      [...(finalQuery.workflowStateId ?? []), ...completed.workflowStateId]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user14967413 for your answer. Now I'm seeing `workflowStateId: Array(3)
0: ['ERTYUIIIIOPPCGVH']
1: ['asdasdasdasda']
2: ['1231231dsxa']`   as console.log. But I would like to console log like `workflowStateId: ['ERTYUIIIIOPPCGVH','asdasdasdasda','1231231dsxa']`  Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @tomo1127 Sorry, my mistake. I added another spread operator (`...completed.workflowStateId`).

Comment: Could you please tell me which part of code you change? Or could you edit above your answer to one you meant? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @tomo1127 I just added three dots (the last occurence, before `completed.workflowStateId`). :-)